# React change variable onChange-method

Tags: reactjs

I am experimenting with React and I have the following problem. Different employees are listed in the "medewerker:" dropdown. When 1 is selected, the data is replaced by the value of the selection using the 'handelChangeEmployee' function in the 'employeeOrder' variable. In the console.log everything changes as expected. Only if I read variable: 'employeeOrder' will it continue to show the previously set value. and this is not being replaced, is this possible? and if so how?

So what I want to achieve is that when a selection is made, the value in the existing variable is replaced with the value of the selection.

The code that I am currently using is:

```
import React from "react";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import { render } from "react-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);


export default function ChaskDesk() {

  const employee = ["Robin","Raoul","Joppe "];
  const service = ["Knippen","Scheren","Wassen"];
  const counting = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  const gender = ["man", "vrouw", "kind"];
  const client = ["Passant"];

  let   employeeOrder = 'Raoul';
  const serviceOrder = [];
  const countingOrder = [];
  const genderOrder = [];
  const clientOrder = "";

  const payment = 0;
  const classes = useStyles();

    const handelChangeGender = function(event){
        genderOrder.push(event.target.value);
        console.log(genderOrder);
    };

    const handelChangeService = function(event){
        serviceOrder.push(event.target.value);
        console.log(serviceOrder);
    };

    let handelChangeEmployee = function(event){
        console.log(employeeOrder);
        employeeOrder = event.target.value;
        console.log(employeeOrder);
    };




  return (
    <div>
      <Container className={classes.containerPixelActive}>
          <h3>Afrekenen</h3>
          <Row className={classes.tablePixelRow}>
            <Col md={8} className={classes.rowChashdesk}>
            <form>
            <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <label>
                        Klant:
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <select >
                        {
                            client.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                    <label>
                        Gender:
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <select onChange={handelChangeGender}>
                        {
                            gender.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Behandeling:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select onChange={handelChangeService}>
                        {
                            service.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Medewerker:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select onChange={handelChangeEmployee}>
                        {
                            employee.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Verkregen behandeling:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Aantal:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select>
                        {
                            counting.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Prijs:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                            <input type="text" name="name"/>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowIcon}>
                        <Close size={20} ></Close>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </form>
            </Col>

            <Col md={3} className={classes.rowChashdesk}>
                <h5>Totaal overzicht</h5>
                <h6>Medewerker</h6>
                <p>{employeeOrder}</p>
                <h6>Behandeling</h6>
                <p>{serviceOrder}</p>
                <h6>Aantal</h6>
                <p>{countingOrder}</p>
                <h6>Klant</h6>
                <p>{clientOrder}</p>
                <h6>Te betalen</h6>
                <p>{payment}</p>
            </Col>

          </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a react component knows to rerender is by your component (or some component above it) settings state. You're not using state, so it doesn't rerender.

Change this:

```
let   employeeOrder = 'Raoul';
```

To this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// ... code omitted

const [employeeOrder, setEmployeeOrder] = useState('Raoul')
```

And change your handler to:

```
const handelChangeEmployee = function(event) {
  setEmployeeOrder(event.target.value)
}
```

You will need to do similar things for genderOrder and ServiceOrder. You can't just push into an array and expect the page to update, you need to set state to a new array to cause the component to rerender. Don't mutate the old array, create a new one, as in:

```
setGenderOrder([...genderOrder, event.target.value])
```

---

For more info on `useState` and other hooks, see [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)